# returning first row in cell array matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array like this,

```
priceList =
[61 x 1 double]    [ 11x1 double]
```

and in each of this arrays, I have some numbers for e.g.

```
5  4
4  3
2  1
1
2
```

so on and so forth, does anyone know how I can return the first row(first index of each array), which will be 5 and 4 in an array based on the above example so something like

```
result =
5
4
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellfun`:

```
result = cellfun( @(x) x(1), priceList )
```

Comment: just to know a little more, how do I make it lets say if I want it to be a 1 x 2 cell or a 2 x 1 cell

Comment: Then use the non-uniform output option: `cellfun(@(x) x(1), priceList, 'UniformOutput', false)`.  Read through `help cellfun` or `doc cellfun` for more information on using the function.